# Output changes after scanf

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm new to C and my code is changing after `scanf`, what should I do?
here the code:

```
void initialize_product(product **product_lst) {
    int result, place, product_list_length = list_length(product_lst);
    char barcode[BARCODE_LENGTH + 1] = "";
    product *product1 = (product *)calloc(1, sizeof(product));
    if (product1 == NULL) {
        printf("Not enough memory");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (product_list_length >= MAX_NUM_PRODUCTS) {
        printf("%s\n", too_much_products);
    }
    (*product1).barcode = (char *)malloc(BARCODE_LENGTH + 1);
    if ((*product1).barcode == NULL) {
        printf("Not enough memory");
        exit(1);
    }
    (*product1).product_name = (char *)malloc(MAX_PRODUCT_NAME_LENGTH + 1);
    if ((*product1).product_name == NULL) {
        printf("Not enough memory");
        exit(1);
    }
    (*product1).product_catagory = (char *)malloc(MAX_CATEGORY_LENGTH + 1);
    if ((*product1).product_catagory == NULL) {
        printf("Not enough memory");
        exit(1);
    }
    (*product1).expire_date = (date *)malloc(sizeof(date));
    if ((*product1).expire_date == NULL) {
        printf("Not enough memory");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("%s", adding_product_barcode);
    scanf("\n%s", &(*(*product1).barcode));
    printf("%s", &(*(*product1).barcode));
    //strcpy(&(*product1).barcode, &barcode);
    result = barcode_compare(product_lst, (*product1).barcode);
    if (result == 0) {
        printf("%s", adding_product_name);
        scanf("\n%[^\n]s", (*product1).product_name);
        printf("%s", adding_product_category);
        scanf("\n%[^\n]s", (*product1).product_catagory);
        printf("%s", adding_product_number);
        scanf("\n%d", &(*product1).available);
        printf("%s", &(*product1).barcode);
        printf("%s", adding_product_price);
        scanf("\n%lf", &(*product1).price);
        strcpy(&(*product1).barcode, &barcode);
        printf("%s", adding_product_date);
        scanf("\n%d/%d/%d", &(*(*product1).expire_date).day, &(*(*product1).expire_date).month, &(*(*product1).expire_date).year);
        printf("%d", (*product1).available);
        printf("The product %s -barcode:%s ,added successfully\n", &(*(*product1).product_name), &(*(*product1).barcode));
        product_lst[product_list_length] = product1;
        printf("%d", (*product1).available);
        printf("barcode is %s, name is %s, catagory is %s, price is %lf, available is %d",
               &(*product_lst[0]).barcode, &(*(*product_lst[0]).product_name),
               &(*(*product_lst[0]).product_catagory), (*product_lst[0]).price,
               (*product_lst[0]).available);
    } else {
        printf("Product already exist, please enter number of products to add: ");
        scanf("%d", &(*product1).available);
        place = barcode_place(product_lst, barcode);
        product_lst[place]->available = (*product1).available;
    }
}
```

After the `scanf` the memory of the barcode is changing, what should I do?
I tried to add some more memory to the `malloc/calloc` and it did not help, I really don't know what to do.

Comment: Why are you using `(*pointer1).available` instead of `pointer1->available`? That's not helping here. Pretty much nobody writes it like that.

Comment: `After the scanf the memory of the barcode is changing` I don't understand what do you mean here ? What is changing ?

Comment: `"\n%[^\n]s` doesn't do what you think it does as `"\n..."` will never match. Why? `'\n'` is *whtespace* and what does including whitespace in your *format string* do? (hint: ignores whitespace). Your entire input routine is more fragile than an eggshell. One stray character and the whole thing explodes -- and you will no know where -- because you fail to ***check the return*** of your input functions. You cannot use any input function correctly without checking the return.... `list_length(product_lst);` also looks suspicious in levels of indirection for `product_lst`...

Comment: Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i had a problem with memory size and the data seemed to leak to other places, also had a syntax problem, but it is all solved now, ty for ur help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line is likely the problem:

```c
strcpy(&(*product1).barcode, &barcode);
```

You don't need the `&`s, as both barcodes are already `char*`. Use:

```c
strcpy((*product1).barcode, barcode);
```

---

**Edit**

I think you might have also confused the order of params in [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/). It seems like `(*product1).barcode` should be the source, not the destination, so the correct form will be:

```c
strcpy(barcode, (*product1).barcode);
```

Comment: the order is right i just needed to remove the &, ty a lot!